# Can Uncontrollable Urges be used to force one Investigator to attack another?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Uncontrollable Urges allows the Keeper to force an Investigator to do an action where the Keeper makes all the choices.

The attacks all seem to state "Attack a monster" but I'm wondering if Uncontrollable Urges overrides this and allows one Investigator to attack another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the answer is no. From page 2 of the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/mom-faq-v1.pdf):

> **Q: Can the keeper use Uncontrollable urges to make an investigator attack
>   another Investigator with a weapon?
>   What about spells?**
>
> A: No. This only
>   allows him to use a spell, equipment,
>   artifact or tome card. If he forces an
>   investigator to cast a spell, he must
>   choose a legal target. To clarify, if
>   a spell says “choose a Monster”, it
>   may not be used against an
>   investigator (even if playing Story
>   5). As another example, the Keeper may
>   not force an investigator to use the
>   “Sedative” equipment on an
>   investigator who does not have a
>   Trauma card.